# check if a lat long is within an extent using open layers 3

Tags: javascript, geolocation, openlayers-3, geoserver

I have a UK county shape file (Multipolygon) using EPSG:4326 in my geoserver. I'm using open layers 3 to load this shape file in my application as below :

```
source = new ol.source.XYZ({url: '/gmaps?zoom={z}&x={x}&y={y}&Layers=UKCounties', crossOrigin: "anonymous"});
countiesLayer = new ol.layer.Tile({source: source});
map.addLayer(countiesLayer);
```

This works well. I have a requirement to get users current location which is done as

```
var coordinate = geolocation.getPosition();
```

I'm able to retrieve the correct lat & long here. Ex : Lat = 53.797534899999995, Lng = -1.5449. now I need to check which of the counties (polygon) these points are in using open layers 3 & Javascript. 
Using Geoserver WFS, I'm able to get the bounding box of each of the counties as

```
$.each(features, function(index, eachFeature) {
            var bbox = eachFeature.properties.bbox;
            if (bbox != null) {
              var bottomLeft = ([bbox[0], bbox[1]]);
              var topRight = ([bbox[2], bbox[3]]);
              var extent = new ol.extent.boundingExtent([bottomLeft, topRight]);

            if (ol.extent.containsXY(extent1,lat,long)) {
                alert("got the feature");
            }
        }

});
```

The issue is my code doesn't print the alert statement.I've also tried using

```
if (ol.extent.containsXY(extent,long,lat))
```

and

```
var XY = ol.proj.transform([long, lat], 'EPSG:4326', 'EPSG:3857');
```

if (ol.extent.containsXY(extent,XY[0],XY[1]))
if (ol.extent.containsXY(extent,XY[1],XY[0]))

But none of these print the alert. Is there anything wrong in this?

Comment: Are you sure your bottomLeft and topRight are right? what is the espg you got after wfs?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to use

```
var XY = ol.extent.applyTransform(extent, ol.proj.getTransform("EPSG:3857", "EPSG:4326"));
```

instead of

```
var XY = ol.proj.transform([long, lat], 'EPSG:4326', 'EPSG:3857');
```

and it works.

Answer (score 0):

Before answering your question, I did not know the method of "*ol.extent.containsXY*".
I used my poor logic! I detected a feature if in a polygon by follwing :

1. transform **feature** and **container**(polygon) to **coordinate [lon, lat]**
2. detect the **container** if contain the **feature**

extent array rule **[minLon, minLat, maxLon, maxLat]**

code snippet: (**my destinationPro:'EPSG:3857', sourcePro:'EPSG:4326'**)

```
QyGIS.prototype.isInner = function(featureExtent, containerExtent) {
    var featureLonLat = ol.proj.transformExtent(featureExtent, destinationPro, sourcePro);
    var containerLonLat = ol.proj.transformExtent(containerExtent, destinationPro, sourcePro);
    // in my condition, the feature is a point, so featureLonLat[0] = featureLonLat[2], featureLonLat[1] = featureLonLat[3]. what's more extent have four value in a array so the loop length is 4
    for (var i = 0; i < featureLonLat.length; i++) {
    /* actually:
     featureLonLat[0] < containerLonLat[0] || featureLonLat[0] > containerLonLat[2]
     featureLonLat[1] < containerLonLat[1] || featureLonLat[1] > containerLonLat[3]
     featureLonLat[2] < containerLonLat[0] || featureLonLat[2] > containerLonLat[2]
     featureLonLat[3] < containerLonLat[1] || featureLonLat[3] > containerLonLat[3]
    */
        if (featureLonLat[i] < containerLonLat[i % 2] || featureLonLat[i] > containerLonLat[i % 2 + 2]) {
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
};

QyGIS.prototype.getInnerFeatures = function(layerName, extent) {
    var self = this;
    var layer = self.getLayer(layerName);
    if (layer) {
        var source = layer.getSource();
        var features = source.getFeatures();
        for (var i = 0; i < features.length; i++) {
            var curFeatureExtent = features[i].getGeometry().getExtent();
            if (self.isInner(curFeatureExtent, extent)) {
                console.log(features[i].get('name') + 'in area');
            }
        }
    }
};
```

[image]

At last, sorry for my poor english if my answer confuse you .